# Excel - Complex puzzle -Disply sub list with only list items marked yes - but insert headers

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

> Win 7 / Excel '16 I have a list of topics in column C  that have
>   yes/no values in column B  and values in column A that increment by
>   one if the value in B = Yes. (see 1st table below = col A uses MAX()+1
>   to increment. I have done this so that i can have another area on the
>   sheet that only displays the items with a yes value, like in the 2nd
>   table. That is accomplished with the vlookup function in the results
>   column G with the look up value of column F.  Column E uses the MATCH
>   function inside the CHOOSE function to indicate when we have reached
>   the end of the topics under the first header, something like this:
>   From Cell E4 to the left of Topic 1
>
> =CHOOSE(MAX(E$2:E3)+1,
>              IF(MATCH(G4,C$1:C$19,0)>7,MAX(E$2:E3)+1,""),
>              IF(MATCH(G4,C$1:C$19,0)>12,MAX(E$2:E3)+1,""),
>              IF(MATCH(G4,C$1:C$19,0)>19,MAX(E$2:E3)+1,""))
>
> My objective is to use the value in column E to determine

1. if the next Topic to be displayed is under the same header, thus no value in col E OR
2. if all the values under Header 0 have been displayed so that there is a value in Col E

> ```
> If the first then display the topic, but if the second display the next header.
> ```

In oder to do the above what i have tried is to wrap the formula in 
Col G inside an IF statement to test if there is a value in Col E.  I have also tried a similar IF statement wrap on Col F to skip the increment if there is a value in Col E.

The problem is that i get a circular reference error, in the first case because the Col E formula is matching the value in Col G and by adding the IF in col G the IF clause is testing the Col E value.  Similar problem with the second case.

All of that is to ask for suggestions for a formula solution, preferably without getting into Functions or VBA, which will allow me to manipulate the results list to include the headers where appropriate.

**Table 1**

[image]

**Table 2**

[image]

Comment: Start the first value in column E with 0 not your Formula then write your Formula in the following rows Keep in mind to write the First formula in E4 (E2 and E3 should be one 0 and one empty)

Comment: cont. -not QUITE clear on what you are suggesting.  Best i can figure is you mean the problem is not having a 0 for the formula to check against the first time. Not sure how that would resolve the circular reference?  The issue is that the Match function, let's say in E6, where the 1 is in the example, refers to cell G6, and if i want the formula in G6 to check if there is a value in E6 to determine if i should insert the next header i get the circular ref.       If you have something else in mind please help me understand.

Comment: I mean set the formula to check the above cells do not include the cell where the formula is written and start with number in the beginning of the column not formula